# How to add custome tab in order page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, sales, dashboard

I need to add custom tab in magento 2.

```
Admin > sales > order next to action and to display content below it.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your **custom_field** in **sales_order** table and now you want to show it in admin order grid.

Add column in **sales_order_grid** table , e.g. "**custom_field**"

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_grid` ADD custom_field VARCHAR( 255 ) after customer_id
```

Create following files in your module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_field</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_field" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Custom Field</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $custom_data = $order->getData("custom_field");
                // returns the name of the column so in this case, it would return custom_field
                // $this->getData('name')
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $custom_data;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

> Note: I have added the direct SQL query for demonstration puropose only.
>   You should use default magento way to add column in the table.

Comment: The requested component ("settings") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation. This error I get